# How to run VACUUM on MBTiles database?

Tags: sqlite, mbtiles

I'm using MapProxy to create an MBTiles database.  After I delete files with `mapproxy-seed.exe --cleanup`, I know that I will need to run vacuum, as in [this mailing list answer](https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/mapproxy/2011-November/000797.html):

> when you remove larger blocks of tiles, you need to do a
>   vacuum

and [this other mailing list answer:](https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/mapproxy/2015-September/002214.html)

> SQLite does not "release memory” if you remove records, but it will re-use the space. 
>   See https://sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html but be aware that your cache in unavailable during VACUUM.

But how do I actually run the VACUUM process?  Do I need to connect to my .mbtiles database with an external manager, or can I run this from the command line somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[VACUUM](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html) is an SQL statement that you run like any other SQL statement.

If you don't have any other mechanism, [download](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html) the tools package and run:

```
sqlite3.exe MyMBTiles.db vacuum
```